# Highlighting Entire Word That Starts With A Pattern in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

I'm having trouble getting pattern matching and replace to work in Word.  I can find the pattern, but I cannot get it to replace the entire word.

Take the following text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
>   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
>   veniam...

I try with the following options:

Find what:     `(<ad*)`

Replace with:  `\1 Highlight`

This successfully finds anything that starts with `ad` and highlights it, but does not highlight the entire word (represented in **bold**):

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur **ad**ipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
>   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim **ad** minim 
>   veniam...

Comment: Does Microsoft Word supports actual regular expressions? What version of Word are you using?

Comment: @JoeP - I am using Office 365, but I believe [wildcard searches](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) have been a part of word for some time.

Comment: In regular expressions, the `ad*` part would match _a followed by zero or any number of d_. 

But it turns out (I should not be surprised) that what Microsoft Word implements as "regular expressions" are not compatible with regular expressions in Perl, Python, Java, etc.

Comment: @JoeP - correct - Word uses its own flavor of Regex.  I've removed that tag because I think it may be confusing the issue.

Comment: As usual, Microsoft is being confusing and imprecise. But I believe that it further muddies the waters by even referring to the Word search capability as a regular expression *at all* — even a crippled or mutated flavor. It’s much much closer to the wildcard/glob syntax that works on the command line; e.g., `del junk*` matches all filenames that begin with `junk`, not all names that contain `jun` followed by zero or more occurrences of `k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to explicitly continue to the end of the word by matching on `(<ad*>)`.

Comment: Are the results the same?

Comment: Well, I fired up a copy of Ms Word and `(<ad*>)` does work for me - _Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur **adipiscing** elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim **ad** minim veniam..._. What result did you get?

Comment: Ok.....that's weird.  Yesterday I couldn't get that to work.  Today?   Did I mention it's been a rough couple of days?  :P  Thank you !